# inserting duotone two layers unicode fontawesome icon inside css content

Tags: css

I want to insert a duotone fontawesome icon and can't find the way, I've always inserted only solid ones.

I'm starting from this:

```
input[type="date"]:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Pro";
  font-weight: 500; 
  content: "\f133";
  color: #555;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

I tried `content: "\f133\f133";` or `content: "\f133\f133\f133";`or putting 2 lines for content, one with `content: "\f133";` and another with `content: "\f133\f133";` but obviously didn't work.

Anyone already worked with this?

Thanks a lot,
Leandro.

Comment: you wanna add new custom icon to Fontawesome or you wanna use a font awesome icon in your HTML. and can you share link of the icon you want to use? correct way is "::after"  not ":after" by the way. https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_after.php

Comment: It looks as though you haven't read the fontawesome documentation on this - duotones require the use of both before and after pseudo elements. See https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/add-icons/pseudo-elements#css-pseudo-elements-and-duotone

Comment: I want to use a font awesome icon (https://fontawesome.com/icons/calendar?s=duotone&f=classic) and I don't know how to put it in the ::after content, and I read the documentation but I don't figure out how to use it, I think documentation applys when I have an <i> element in the html, and it's not the case because I'm trying to replace the default datepicker icon, so I'm adding this content to the datepicker::after and if I use a before, I would be adding an icon splitted in 2 parts, one before and one after the input.